# JAR plugins implementation

Tags: java, reflection, plugins, groovy, jar

Let us have a Groovy/Java application that should use a set of classes, defined in external `*.jar`-files (suppose they are located near the main executable jar).

So, the main class (let us call it `Main`) should load `plugin.jar` file at runtime and call some instance method on the class, defined in that jar (for some convention, suppose the class has the name as its jar - `Plugin` in our case).

The `Main` class could not know which plugins it has until it is runned. Let's throw away the `CLASSPATH` and `java -jar` run arguments and just do the magic with code only.

So, how this could be done and how the `plugin.jar` should be created (using Eclipse in my case) in order to be correctly loaded?

**PS:** yeah, i do compile my groovy sources into jar file. But i need to perform class loading and invoke exactly on-the-fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The secret was really simple!

Using `URLClassLoader` does the trick.

So, **Groovy** code:

```
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader((URL[]) [
    new File("C:\\Users\\errorist\\workspace\\javatest1\\bin\\").toURI().toURL()
])

Class c = loader.loadClass("src.SomeClass1")

c.invokeMethod("main", (String[]) ["Hello", "World"])
```

And the **Java** one:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\errorist\\workspace\\javatest1\\bin\\");
URL[] urls = new URL[] { file.toURI().toURL() };
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
Class c = loader.loadClass("src.SomeClass1");
c.invokeMethod("main", new String[] { "Hello", "World!" });
```

Answer (score 1):

The [OSGi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) framework supports dynamic loading of plug-ins. There are multiple implementations, including [Equinox](http://eclipse.org/equinox/), which underpins Eclipse itself.

Comment: well, thanks, but i wish if i could do that without third-parties =)